# LINQ: How to Select specific columns using IQueryable()

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I need to select only two columns from Hospital table, HospitalId and Name.
i tried the below code it selects all columns from Hospital table which lead to slow performance. Please help me to select only two columns from Hospital table

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetAvailableHospitalsByAjax(System.Guid? DirectorateOfHealthID = null, System.Guid? UnitTypeID = null, string DeviceTypeIDs = null)
{
    Context db = new Context();
    var query = db.Hospitals.AsQueryable();
    if (UnitTypeID != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(j => j.HospitalDepartments.Any(www => www.Units.Any(u => u.UnitTypeID == UnitTypeID)));
    }

    if (DirectorateOfHealthID != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(h => h.DirectorateHealthID == DirectorateOfHealthID);
    }


    query = query.Where(j => j.HospitalDepartments.Any(u => u.Units.Any(d => d.Devices.Any(s => s.Status == Enums.DeviceStatus.Free)))
    && j.HospitalDepartments.Any(hd => hd.Units.Any(u => u.Beds.Any(b => b.Status == Enums.BedStatus.Free))));



    var list = query.ToList().Select(w => new HospitalInfo()
    {
        Id = w.ID,
        Name = w.Name 

    }).ToList();


    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, list);
}
```

Comment: first select then tolist

Answer (score 3):

`IQueryable<T>` executes select query on server side with all filters. Hence does less work and becomes fast.

`IEnumerable<T>` executes select query on server side, load data in-memory on client side and then filter data. Hence does more work and becomes slow.

`List<T>` is just an output format, and while it implements `IEnumerable<T>`, is not directly related to querying.

So,

```
var list = query.ToList().Select(w => new HospitalInfo()
    {
        Id = w.ID,
        Name = w.Name 

    }).ToList();
```

In your code you use `query.ToList()`. This means at first it pull all data into memory then apply `Select` query.If you want to retrieve HospitalID and Name then remove `ToList()` then your code like

```
   var list = query.Select(w => new HospitalInfo
        {
            Id = w.ID,
            Name = w.Name     
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `ToList` call before the projection:

```
  var list = query.Select(w => new HospitalInfo()
  {
     Id = w.ID,
     Name = w.Name 

  }).ToList();
```

With that `ToList` call you are materializing your query before do the projection

Answer (score 0):

Because you do `query.ToList()` this materialises the *entire* query with all columns into memory. It's actually a bad habit to get into. Instead, remove that, you already have it at the end anyway. The `Select` projection you have *will* only retrieve the relevant columns though:

```
var list = query.Select(w => new HospitalInfo()
{
    Id = w.ID,
    Name = w.Name 

}).ToList();
```